# How to return value from JavaScript using Selenium?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I executed JavaScript using [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287791/how-to-call-js-file-through-selenium?answertab=votes#tab-top) and I want to return a value from this script.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can just return the value like this:

Java:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;         
js.executeScript("return document.title");
```

Python:

```
driver.execute_script("return document.title")
driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('.somecssclass')")
```

Comment: Thanks @Jochen, but I am getting a value in the JS file on `window.addEventListener('click', function (e) {return e}, false);` I want that **event e** .

Comment: Thank you @Jochen this helped.

Comment: I'm really impressed with Selenium's handling of JavaScript. Not only does it allow you to return values as shown above, but it also throws a `JavascriptException` in case of error. You can handle asynchronous calls by adding global variables to the `window`, and then checking on the variable later with another call!

Comment: afaik this doesn't work in current version of selenium w/ ChromeDriver. Chrome result in error.  Illegal return statement

Answer (score 10):

I appended the value to be returned using (in .js file):

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<div style="display:none;" id="some_id">' + value_to_be_returned + '</div>';
```

and accessed the value in java using (in .java file):

```
String return_value = (String) js.executeScript("return document.getElementById('some_id').innerHTML");
```

Answer (score 8):

If the Javascript you want to execute is synchronous then the javascript return value will be assigned to the result of `driver.execute_script()` method — this is probably what you would expect, and follows the [least surprise principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment):

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# make sure you have a `return` in the js code
js_url = driver.execute_script("return window.location.href")
print(js_url)
```

For asynchronous calls use [`driver.execute_async_script`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_async_script):

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

print(driver.execute_async_script('''
    fetch('http://httpbin.org/get')
         .then(resp=>resp.json())
         .then(data=>{alert(JSON.stringify(data)
         )});
'''))
```

For the specific case of [jQuery.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) you can also force the call to be synchronous by passing `async: false` (by default it is asynchronous), for example the following code will return the http response text synchronously:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

http_response = driver.execute_script("""
return $.ajax({
    url: 'http://httpbin.org/get', 
    async: false
}).responseText""")

print(http_response)
```

Answer (score 4):

For asynchronous I used the following:

```
result = driver.executeAsyncScript(
  "var callback = arguments[arguments.length-1];" + 
  "$.ajax('someurl').success(function(data){ callback(data); });"
);
```

Comment: I think this answer is great for getting asynchronous values, The other answer uses `alert(...)`, but this answer actually returns the result of the asynchronous Javascript operation so it's available in your Java/Selenium code!

I made a change to use the *last* argument  as the callback (vs the first argument), and to store the value into a Java variable (which demonstrates the power of this approach, [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28066902/1175496))