# xpath to find pseudo-element ::after in side a div element with out any content

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to write xpath to find a checkbox selected or not, this checkbox is being changed using css ::after element. Below are two elements I have

```html
//div[@class='FormBlock-formItem2' and .//text()='Scoped In']//div[@class='FormBlock-controlIndicator']
```

[image: two elements for checkboxes]

I need to find that 'Scoped Out' is not selected and 'Scoped In' is selected. The only difference I see is '::after' in the second section of checkbox. 
I tried the xpath :" **//div[@class='FormBlock-formItem2' and .//text()='Scoped In']//div[@class='FormBlock-controlIndicator']** " but this is finding the 'Scoped In' element but I am not able to verify if its checked or not. Struggling from couple of days. Kindly help.

Comment: Pseudo-elements don't exist in the DOM tree (hence the name), therefore they cannot be selected with XPath.

Comment: @Tomalak : Hi, Thanks for the comment,I got to know this point after some search in google, but is there any way to find if the checkbox is selected or not?

Comment: Not without asking Javascript, I would assume.

Comment: @Naveenkumar Can you update the question with text based formatted _HTML_ of either of the element 1)Without being checked and 2)Being checked?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check code below if return correct true/false:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[./div[@class='FormBlock-itemText' and .='Scope In']]/input")).isSelected();
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, that's not possible with XPath. As mentioned by Tomalak, Pseudo-elements don't exist in the DOM tree (hence the name), therefore they cannot be selected with XPath and Selenium does not expose them as well. In general, `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements are used for styling of containing element.

If you want to check whether `::before` or `::after` pseudo-elements are present or what's their content you can use a CSS selector, like this:

```js
console.log(window.window.getComputedStyle(
 document.querySelector('#item'), ':begin'
));
//or
window.getComputedStyle(
 document.querySelector('#item'), ':after'
).getPropertyValue('color');
```

```css
#item::after {
    content: 'checked';
    color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div id="item">
</div>
```

And then use a `JavascriptExecutor` to inject the JS into the browser and [get the return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40735442/how-to-return-value-from-javascript-using-selenium):

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;         
js.executeScript("return document.title");
```

Comment: I was wondering though... CSS is declarative - `::before` and `::after` only exist *because of* something tangible in the DOM tree. Their existence is governed by a CSS rule, therefore it must be possible to infer that they exist by applying same CSS rule in selenium.

Comment: @wp78de Hi , thanks for the response, I am not able to use my xpath //div[@class='FormBlock-formBlock' and .//text()='Scope Status']//div[(@class='FormBlock-formItem' or @class='FormBlock-formItem2') and .//text()='Scoped In']//div[@class='FormBlock-controlIndicator']  in the querySelector, and I am not able to convert my xpath to css as css wont support traversing with conditions like in my xpath. How can I execute my xpath in document..

Comment: Hi, I tried this but its returning only rgb(0,0,0) but not the actual color :     window.getComputedStyle(
 document.evaluate("//div[@class='FormBlock-formBlock' and .//text()='Scope Status']//div[(@class='FormBlock-formItem' or @class='FormBlock-formItem2') and .//text()='Scoped In']//div[@class='FormBlock-controlIndicator']", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null ).iterateNext(), ':after'
).getPropertyValue('background');

Answer (score 1):

You can try using UI state pseudo-classes, using which we can find elements for various states, such as when control is enabled, disabled, and checked.

Pseudo-classes with input example are -

1. input:enabled - This will find all the elements that are enabled for user input.
2. input:disabled - This will find all the elements that are disabled for user input.
3. **input:checked** - This will find all the elements(check boxes) that are checked.

   WebElement checkBoxStatus = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input:checked"));

More details can be found here on w3c [site](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below screenshot. I try using the CSS selector and checking visibility of element located with wait driver time. It worked.

[Html code with after:: pseudo code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9F2Hm.jpg)

[python code with css selector and wait time that worked out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdVPZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use XPath in Selenium WebDriver to access pseudo-elements, but not directly - via JavascriptExecutor.

1. Find the needed **parent** element for pseudo-element by XPath and Selenium, save it as e.g. *webElement*.
2. Call *window.getComputedStyle()* function via Selenium [JavascriptExecutor](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html), use  *webElement* as parameter. It can be accessible in script by *arguments[0]* variable.

```java
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='FormBlock-controlIndicator']");
String script = "return window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0],':after').getPropertyValue('content')";
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)_driver;
String content = (String) js.ExecuteScript(script, webElement);
```