# Click on XPath-selected href link in Nightwatch?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, href, nightwatch

How to click on a `href` link in Nightwatch?

The `href` text is identical to each other so I can't use XPath text.

I tried:

`browser.useXpath().click("//a[href='./basket/removeItem.html?id=5de6710f75a5750f3d88495b')]");`

but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

At minimal, correct your XPath to add `@` in front of the `href` *attribute* and remove the spurious `)`:

```
//a[@href='./basket/removeItem.html?id=5de6710f75a5750f3d88495b')]
    ^add                                                        ^delete
```

If `id` variation is a problem, exclude it via `starts-with()`:

```
//a[starts-with(@href, './basket/removeItem.html')]
```

If there are multiple such `@href` attributes on the page, you can select one via indexing (as [shown by @Christine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59160569/290085), +1):

```
//a[starts-with(@href, './basket/removeItem.html')][1]
```

---

### Actual problem

OP added a link to an image (ugh) of the HTML that shows that the targeted `a` link is in the document by virtue of a  `::before` [**CSS *pseudo element***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements).  In such cases, the element doesn't actually exist in the DOM to be selected as usual.

### See also:

- [Selecting and manipulating CSS pseudo-elements such as ::before and ::after using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5041494/290085)
- [Extracting content in :after using XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40885637/290085)
- [xpath to find pseudo-element ::after in side a div element with out any content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51992258/290085)

Comment: `NoSuchElementError: An error occurred while running .click() command on <a[@href='./basket/removeItem.html?id=5de6710f75a5750f3d88495b']>: `

The part im trying to get looks like this [link](https://ibb.co/TtsXPrL). The ID is unique btw (after the href, the tst_remove_from_basket is identical to each remove item)

Comment: If the id in the `href` is unique, then it seems like the XPath using `starts-with()` should handle that case.

Comment: `Error while running .locateMultipleElements() protocol action: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression a[starts-with(@href, './basket/removeItem.html?id=5de6710f75a5750f3d88495b') because of the following error:

   NoSuchElementError: An error occurred while running .click() command on <a[starts-with(@href, './basket/removeItem.html?id=5de6710f75a5750f3d88495b')>:`

Comment: Issue is due to `::before` pseudo element.   Answer updated to address.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Perhaps this will work, but this does solution does not fit in my project. My apologies for the post to image of HTML.

Comment: @kjhughes can you use CSS selector to bypass the ::after and use the href id?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the index in XPath to pick either the first or second link.

For the first link:

```
//a[@id='tst_remove_from_basket'][1]
```

For the second link:

```
//a[@id='tst_remove_from_basket'][2]
```

Comment: NoSuchElementError: An error occurred while running .click() command on <a[@href='./basket/removeItem.html?id=5de6710f75a5750f3d88495b']>: The part im trying to get looks like this link. The ID is unique btw (after the href, the tst_remove_from_basket is identical to each remove item)

Comment: I see. I updated my answer to query on the ID attribute since they are identical, then use indexing to click either first or second link.

Comment: use it like : `browser.useXpath().click("a[@id='tst_remove_from_basket'][1]");` because that isn't working