# How to execute Javascript in browser with Python Selenium and record output

Tags: python, selenium, browser

I am inquiring about executing javascript in the browser with selenium. I've seen plenty of ways how to do this, however, saving the output to a variable seems to be something else.

```
r = driver.execute_script("`; ${document.cookie}`.split(`; bearer_token=`).pop().split(';').shift()")
```

This makes R = None, which is not the output of the code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40735442/how-to-return-value-from-javascript-using-selenium

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the return statement:

```
r = driver.execute_script("return 2+2")
print(r)
```

will print `4`.

And it will print `None` without return.

Answer (score -1):

`execute_script()` function in the selenium works for executing something particularly in the specific browser tab only, I am sure that the outputs won't be stored in a python variable. Instead I recommend to save the cookies in your local dir and later perform your tasks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).